# Why does Subversion/TortoiseSVN skip revision numbers if a file has only been changed one time?

Tags: tortoisesvn, numbers, revision, skip

I am fairly new to Subversion/TortoiseSVN and I want to know if there is a way to prevent Subversion from skipping revision numbers on files so that I can track the amount of time a file is changed based on it's revision number:

Example: I have A.txt, B.txt, and C.txt
Revision 1: (added the files to repository)
   A.txt :1
   B.txt :1
   C.txt :1

Revision 2: (edited files: A.txt and B.txt)
   A.txt :2
   B.txt :2
   C.txt :1

Revision 3: (edited files: A.txt and C.txt)
   A.txt :3
   B.txt :2
   C.txt :3 <---------I want this "3" to be a 2**********

******** I made one change to C.txt and I want the revision number to increase one time (not skip 2 and go straight to 3).  I understand why Subversion/TortoiseSVN does it this way and how to follow it, but for the project I am working on, I want to do this a different way.  I have read everywhere and can't seem to find anyone else with this issue. Any suggestions?

Thanks

I am new at this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revision numbers do not count how often a particular controlled artifact has been modified.  Rather, they track a version of the entire set of artifacts.  This way you can retrieve, say, version 96 and know based on that number that you have exactly the set of files that you need.

This is different from CVS or VSS where version numbers are tracked on a per-file basis and you need a different technique to get a consistent entire-project view.  (E.g., "labels" in VSS)

Comment: THanks for you help I think I figured out a soln

Comment: It answers the question because it explains how the numbers "skip".  It looks like versions on a file are skipped because the file hasn't changed for one or more checkins.

Answer (score 3):

subversion handles the revision number per project not per file as cvs used to

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can't do that in Subversion.  And you don't need to.  If you want to know how many revisions have been made to a particular file, use `svn log`.